# multiple inheritance with same attribute in super class

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

In multiple inheritance c++ with same attribute in suber class like this code

```
class A{
protected :
    int var;
}

class B{
protected :
    int var;    
}

class C: public A,B{

    C(){
        A::var=3;
        B::var=5;
    }
}
```

i must write A::var or B::var to determine the super class 
is there any way to redefine the attribute in C class like

```
#define AA = A::var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you may `#define` everything. But this is not a good altitude. Also `AA` would be defined everywhere in your code, not only in the scope of `class C`.

You may add:

```
using A::var;
```

So that `var` would be `A::var` by default.

Besides of this you may add a member function that would return you a reference to your member variable, if you don't want to add `A::` everywhere.